# Sympy doing subs multiple times

Tags: sympy

I am using `isympy` and have the expression:

```
expr = x + 2 * y
```

And I want to substitute x with the values in [0, 1, 2, 3]. Currently I am doing:

```
Eq(Symbol('X_0'), expr.subs(x, 0))
Eq(Symbol('X_1'), expr.subs(x, 1))
Eq(Symbol('X_2'), expr.subs(x, 2))
Eq(Symbol('X_3'), expr.subs(x, 3))
```

Output:

```
X₀ = 2⋅y
X₁ = 2⋅y + 1
X₂ = 2⋅y + 2
X₃ = 2⋅y + 3
```

Is there are a better way to do this? I would like `Xₖ` to be a function which can take a list of `k` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to return a list given a list input:

```
In [1]: expr=x+2*y

In [2]: [expr.subs(x,i) for i in range(4)]
Out[2]: [2⋅y, 2⋅y + 1, 2⋅y + 2, 2⋅y + 3]
```

This can of course be cast as a function.